Can't delete folder in sidebar. No unpin option
There's a folder in my sidebar. That folder is named after external drive that I have:

I don't know what I did for that folder to appear and now it's really annoying. I think it's a corrupted folder of my external drive which is One Touch (D). When I right click it, it doesn't have the unpin option. Only shows this:

When I tried to expand it, it showed nothing. When I clicked properties of that folder, it showed nothing like this:

It has no directory so I can't delete it from cmd.
One Touch (D) folder (yellow manilla folder not the external drive) is above This PC but still in This PC section:

Anyone have solutions for this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
